# Set User property for an ApiController in Unit Test

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, iprincipal

My unit tests for an ApiController uses some helpers methods to instantiate the controller:

```
public static ResourcesController SetupResourcesController(HttpRequestMessage request, IResourceMetadataRepository repo, IUnitOfWorkService unitOfWorkService)
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    var defaultRoute = config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(RouteNames.DefaultApi , "api/{controller}/{id}");
    var routeData = new HttpRouteData(defaultRoute, new HttpRouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "resources" } });

    var resourcesController = new ResourcesController(repo, unitOfWorkService)
    {
        ControllerContext = new HttpControllerContext(config, routeData, request),
        Request = request
    };
    resourcesController.Request.Properties.Add(HttpPropertyKeys.HttpRouteDataKey, routeData);
    resourcesController.Request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey] = config;

    // Compilation fail: The Property 'System.Web.Http.ApiController.User' has no setter.
    resourcesController.User = myStubUserPrincipal;

    return resourcesController;
}
```

My question is: how to set the User property for the controller?

I've tried:

```
request.Properties.Add("MS_UserPrincipal", myStubUserPrincipal);
```

But this doesn't work either (the resourcesController.User property remains null).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Set the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`, and that will initialize the `User` property in the controller automatically.

For people that see this answer, but have no idea how to set `CurrentPrincipal`.:
[This code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentprincipal.aspx) is extracted from MSDN.

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal
(
   new GenericIdentity("Bob", "Passport"),
   new[] {"managers", "executives"}
);
```

Comment: Thanks Pablo! Seems too simple to be true but yes; setting the Thread.CurrentPrincipal property within my test setup code did the trick!

Comment: Great! I was searching on how to mock/fake everything and this is a simple way to do it.

Comment: For people that see this answer, but have no idea how to set CurrentPrincipal. This code is extracted from MSDN. 

Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("Bob", "Passport"), new[] {"managers", "executives"}); http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentprincipal.aspx

Add this to your answer if you want.

Comment: I tried to use this method in my unit tests for Web Api 2, but the User property is always null.

Comment: This works in Web Api 2 but you need to use "RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name" to get the current user logged in, this works for unit testing and runtime aswell.

Comment: How do you get the User property to have the right value.  I am using it in the actual controllers, so the test fails because the User is null.

Comment: You can also set it directly on the controller like so: `resourcesController.RequestContext.Principal = new ...`

Comment: @Nebula you should post your comment as another answer

Answer (score 13):

A cleaner way would be to mock away `IPrincipal` and `HttpRequestContext`, for example using Moq:

```
var userMock = new Mock<IPrincipal>();
userMock.Setup(p => p.IsInRole("admin")).Returns(true);
userMock.SetupGet(p => p.Identity.Name).Returns("tester");
userMock.SetupGet(p => p.Identity.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true);

var requestContext = new Mock<HttpRequestContext>();
requestContext.Setup(x => x.Principal).Returns(userMock.Object);

var controller = new ControllerToTest()
{
    RequestContext = requestContext.Object,
    Request = new HttpRequestMessage(),
    Configuration = new HttpConfiguration()
};
```